# How to connect a mysql server to grafana?

Tags: mysql, connection, grafana

I'm new on grafana and I need to connect my database (mysql) to it.

I tried to configure the custom.ini file as follow,

I added the next section on database

```
#################################### Database 
####################################
type = mysql
host = localhost:3306
name = grafana (db on my sql server)
user = grafana (user on my sql server)
#### If the password contains # or ; you have to wrap it with triple quotes. 
Ex “”"#password;"""
password =***** (password of my sql user)
```

and the next section on session

```
#################################### Session ####################################
[session]


provider = mysql (at the beginning)

provider_config = grafana:*******@tcp(localhost:3306)/grafana 
provider = mysql (at the end)
```

When I try to connect to the serve I get this error : “Service init failed: Migration failed err: this authentication plugin is not supported”

I’m new on grafana and I don’t know if I have to set more thinks in the custom.ini

If someone can figure out what is wrong here I will be the happiest man on the world :D

Thanks for the time you spent reading this and a big big thanks to the savior !!

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the problem. The fact is that mysql 8 has some permission faeture which brings a lot of issue for connecting to grafana or read files. So I install mysql 5.7 instead and all was fine !